# Get the required sql query result

Tags: mysql, sql

```
mysql> select calendar.calId,calendar.cdate,lsUsers.userId,
              apptActual.OPDID,count(*) 
        from calendar 
        LEFT JOIN apptActual on calendar.calId=apptActual.calendarId
        LEFT JOIN lsUsers on lsUsers.userId=apptActual.OPDID 
        group by 1,2,3,4 order by 3
        desc limit 10;
```

Result is:

```
+-------+------------+--------+-------+----------+
| calId | cdate      | userId | OPDID | count(*) |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+----------+
|    76 | 2016-03-16 |     11 |    11 |        1 |
|    75 | 2016-03-15 |     11 |    11 |        1 |
|    77 | 2016-03-17 |      9 |     9 |        1 |
|    75 | 2016-03-15 |      8 |     8 |        1 |
|    75 | 2016-03-15 |      1 |     1 |        1 |
|  1279 | 2019-07-02 |   NULL |  NULL |        1 |
|  1287 | 2019-07-10 |   NULL |  NULL |        1 |
|  1295 | 2019-07-18 |   NULL |  NULL |        1 |
|  1303 | 2019-07-26 |   NULL |  NULL |        1 |
|  1311 | 2019-08-03 |   NULL |  NULL |        1 |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+----------+
10 rows in set (0.34 sec)
```

By using above query I am getting result as above, but I need result result like below (all userId's has to come.)

```
+-------+------------+--------+-------+----------+
| calId | cdate      | userId | OPDID | count(*) |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+----------+
|    76 | 2016-03-16 |     11 |    11 |        1 |
|    75 | 2016-03-15 |     11 |    11 |        1 |
|    77 | 2016-03-17 |      9 |     9 |        1 |
|    75 | 2016-03-15 |      8 |     8 |        1 |
|    75 | 2016-03-15 |      1 |     1 |        1 |
|  1279 | 2019-07-02 |      4 |  NULL |        1 |
|  1287 | 2019-07-10 |      21|  NULL |        1 |
|  1295 | 2019-07-18 |      3 |  NULL |        1 |
|  1303 | 2019-07-26 |      7 |  NULL |        1 |
|  1311 | 2019-08-03 |      5 |  NULL |        1 |
+-------+------------+--------+-------+----------+
```

Please suggest me how to get result as above!

Comment: I dont undertstand what you're trying to do so I can't answer

Comment: But how are we supposed to find out which userId to return, when there are no userId...? Perhaps you should do a regular inner join instead of left join...?

Answer (score 0):

If you join lsUsers on userId = appActual.OPDID you will get what you ask for: usedId (NULL) = OPDID (NULL). Is there any other way to join lsUsers?